# Power table using while loop formatting and logic error

Tags: java, string, algorithm, for-loop, math

I am trying to make a table from 1 - 5, which displays there power up to 6 values.

so for example, the 2 column would go from, 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 and would stop there.

I am having trouble getting proper table format. Since the numbers don't align where they should be.

for example:

the problem I am facing right now is this

1   2   3  4  5
1   1   1  1  1   1   1  2  4  8  16 and so and so on

any well would be appreciated, my code is down below.

```
 int powNumb=5;
 int powValue=6;

for (int i = 1; i <= powValue; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%10d",i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 1; i <= powNumb; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <=powValue; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%10.0f",Math.pow(i, j));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you

```
for (int i = 1; i <= powNumb; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%10d", i); //Print the number (1st col)
    for (int j = 0; j <= powValue; j++) { //This loop prints the powers of the curent number 'i'
        System.out.printf("%10.0f", Math.pow(i, j));
    }
    System.out.println(); //To end the current row
}
```

This prints

```
num   num^0  num^1  num^2 ... num^powValue
```

where num is from 1 to `powNumb`

Output

```
 1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
 2         1         2         4         8        16        32        64
 3         1         3         9        27        81       243       729
 4         1         4        16        64       256      1024      4096
 5         1         5        25       125       625      3125     15625
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean the same base for every element, so there is no need for inner loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= powNumb; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%10.0f", Math.pow(powValue, i));
}
```

This way the base of power is always `powValue`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a `println` statement somewhere in your inner for loop to separate the rows.

Second, you need to switch the `i` and `j` in your call to `Math.pow`. Because with how it's currently set up, each row is value `i = row number` to powers 0 through 6. For example, the first row would be `1^0 1^1 1^2 1^3 1^4 1^5 1^6`. Then, the second row would be `2^0 2^1 2^2 2^3 2^4 2^5 2^6`  However, you want the first row to be `1^0 2^0 3^0 4^0 5^0`, second row `1^1 2^1 3^1 4^1 5^1`, etc. So your code should be changed to something like this,

```
int powNumb=5;
int powValue=6;

for (int i = 1; i <= powNumb; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%10d",i);
}
for (int i = 0; i <= powValue; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 1; j <=powNumb; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%10.0f",Math.pow(j, i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 1         2         3         4         5
 1         1         1         1         1
 1         2         3         4         5
 1         4         9        16        25
 1         8        27        64       125
 1        16        81       256       625
 1        32       243      1024      3125
 1        64       729      4096     15625
```

Also, I had to switch `powNumb` and `powValue` in the for loop conditions.